# Angular2 get active route

Tags: angular, routes

After update to Angular2 rc2, and Angular2 rc3, I have error

"Property 'urlTree' does not exist on type 'Router'"

My function

```
isRouteActive(routePath) {
    return this.router.urlTree.contains(this.router.createUrlTree(routePath));
}
```

How to get active link in angular2 rc3 ?

Answer (score 6):

If you are going to style some element according to **activeRoute** you can use the directive `[routerLinkActive]="['your-class-name']"` to the element.

[routerLinkActive directive source](https://github.com/angular/vladivostok/blob/master/src/directives/router_link_active.ts)

---

### **UPDATE**

**Old style (with router-deprecated):**
**`html layout`**

```
<li [class.active]="isActive(['Dashboard'])">
    <a [routerLink]="['dashboard']"><span class="nav-label">Dashboard</span></a>
</li>
```

**`*.ts component`**

```
isActive(instruction: any[]): boolean {
    return this.router.isRouteActive(this.router.generate(instruction));
}
```

**New style (with router version 3.0.0-alpha.7):**
**`only html layout needed`**

```
<li [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
    <a [routerLink]="['dashboard']"><span class="nav-label">Dashboard</span></a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 3):

You might want to use `ActivatedRoute`

```ts
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'contacts-detail',
  ...
})
export class ContactsDetailComponent {

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With Angular 2 rc4 using router 3.0.0-beta.2 the Directive comment states:

```
<a routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}" [routerLink]="['/']">HOME</a>
```

However this also works:

```
<a [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}" [routerLink]="['/']">HOME</a>
```

If [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}" is omitted the class will not be removed when the route is inactive.

See: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/router/src/directives/router_link_active.ts